# How to take backup of Azure fileshares

Tags: azure, backup, azure-storage, azure-files

I have created Azure file share and used it as a persistent storage for my application deployed in openshift.

The data is important and I need to take backups of my azure files also periodically.

How to take backup of Azure file shares inside storage account?

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to utilize a Recovery Services vault.
Thorough guidance is available at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-afs

Comment: can you please comment on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65137145/network-policy-in-kubernetes-not-working-in-different-namespaces